# How to make RxJava interval unstoppable even on error?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I face a problem with rxJava interval when some method throws an exception interval stop working. For continued work, I add `retryWhen()` operator but this does not work? How to resume work when an error/exception happens?

```
Flowable.interval(
            0,
            Constants.INTERVAL,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            Schedulers.io()
        ).map { prepareData() }
.flatMap { sendRequestToServer() }
.retryWhen { flowable -> flowable.delay(Constants.RETRY_ON_FAILURE_TIME, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS) }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add some wrapper for Server response.
For example:

```
sealed class Response {
    data class Success(/*some fields here*/): Response
    data class Error(val error: Throwable): Response
}
```

after that use `onErrorReturn` method:

```
// fun sendRequestToServer() returns Flowable<Response.Success>

val responseFlowable: Flowable<Response> = Flowable.interval(
        0,
        Constants.INTERVAL,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        Schedulers.io())
    .map { prepareData() }
    .flatMap { sendRequestToServer().onErrorReturn { Response.Error(it) } }
```